# Google Analtyics: Just Show All-Time Pageviews Data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This applies to both Google Analytics and Google Analytics Core API. I've been using Analytics since the launch of site in 2008.

I want to use Analytics to keep track of pageviews for content urls, but thought there was an easy way to just get all-time pageviews number by URL.

Instead, I have to put the date range from Feb 1,2008 until today, and Google Analytics fails to run such a query or bugs out and returns bad information. It prefers me to run every few months as periods, but then I'd need to do about 32 requests per URL.

I just want all-time pageview data (for the requested page url), but there does not seem an option for this.

All feedback appreciated.

Cheers
Ryan

Comment: GA always requires a timeframe. However I can pull pageviews from the last 10 years from my accounts in a single query (for up to 10 000 paths), which makes me suspect you are looking for more than pageviews (or have more dimensions than just the page path). It would help if you could post an example query and the specific error message your are receiving.

Comment: Sure! Here is what I'm running:

`return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2008-01-01',
       'today',
       'ga:pageviews',
        array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/transformers',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'max-results' => '1'));
}`
This query will either return the wrong number or run indefinitely until an error comes back. If I shrink to a month it runs fine.
Any optimization greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey @EikePierstorff - Does that look right or is my request format not the most efficient?

Comment: That looks reasonable, but you might save API requests if you run the query without a filter and store the result (set the max results parameter to return the possible maximum row numner of 10 000). I still do not understand why you have to issue multiple requests per page path.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - there has to be something wrong. I'm requesting stats on a single URL for a max-results of 1. It just times out, the 8-year date range is too large.

`return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2008-01-01',
       'today',
       'ga:pageviews',
        array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/transformers',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'max-results' => '1'));
}`

http://www.traileraddict.com/util/analytics/test.php

That will timeout.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - i should point out that my PHP has max_execution_time of 30 seconds, so it times out after that. Should I increase this? I'm not doing anything but waiting on  the request to var_dump.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Sorry for all the comments. But it looks like it is grabbing URLs off domain as well. I see LockerDome showing up a lot when I do more of a wildcard. Where is the setting to only include domain pages?